# glue cannot interpolate functions into strings. * object 'n' is a function

Tags: gtsummary

I'm loving gtsummary. I write a lot of reports and love my pretty tables!

I've run into a problem when I updated.
I just updated to using all_stat_cols(TRUE) instead of stat_by.
I'm getting an error with I try to include {level} or {n} when I add overall.

It works if stat_0 isn't included, so I tried with with all_stat_cols(FALSE) and a separate stat_0 ~ "Total n = {n}", but get the error "Error: glue cannot interpolate functions into strings. * object 'n' is a function."

This works:

```
 nr %>%
  select(gender, year) %>%
     tbl_summary (by = gender, missing = "no")  %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  add_overall(last=TRUE) %>%
  modify_footnote(update = everything() ~ NA) %>%
  modify_header(update = list(label ~ "",
                all_stat_cols(FALSE) ~ "{level}\n n = {n}\n"))
```

[image]

But I also want my overall to be changed "Total n = 17" like this:

```
nr %>%
  select(gender, year) %>%
     tbl_summary (by = gender, missing = "no")  %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  add_overall(last=TRUE) %>%
  modify_footnote(update = everything() ~ NA) %>%
  modify_header(update = list(label ~ "",
                all_stat_cols(FALSE) ~ "{level}\n n = {n}\n",
                stat_0 ~ "Total\n = {n}"))
```

But get this error:

> Error: glue cannot interpolate functions into strings. * object 'n' is a function.

I also want to remove the first row (Year level) if anyone knows how to do that too!

Any help or ideas would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello! The reason you're getting an error is because little *n* represents the in the `by=` group, and big *N* is the overall number of obs. When you try to use little *n* in the header for the overall column you get the error because it's not defined.

Change the little *n* to big *N*, and you should be all set! Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #BlackLivesMatter
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.1'

tbl <-
  trial %>%
  select(trt, age, grade) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") %>%
  add_overall() %>%
  modify_header(
    update = list(label ~ "",
                  all_stat_cols(FALSE) ~ "{level}\n n = {n}\n",
                  stat_0 ~ "Total\n = {N}")
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much! Don't I feel foolish! Is there a way to remove the first row (where it says Year level)? Appreciate your help and thanks for the gtsummary package - it's awesome.

Comment: Yeah, there is a function in gtsummary called `remove_row_type()`